# Determining marginal pmf in a smoking survey

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a joint pmf but I'm stuck at finding a marginal pmf. Here's a problem:

In a smoking survey 78% of students prefer dating non-smokers, 1% prefer dating smokers, and 21% don't care. Suppose we chose seven students randomly. Let X equal the number who prefer to date nonsmokers and Y be those who prefer dating smokers.

The joint pmf of x and y I found is: $7Cx * 7-x C y *0.78^x (0.21)^{7-x-y} (0.01)^y$

How would you find the marginal pmf of X with its support?

I know its the sum of all y values of the joint pmf but I think you're not supposed to have a y variable here. Can anyone explain this part to me?

Comment: Does your probability mass function add up to $1$?  Your "$7Cx * 7$" looks very large

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way is to ignore information not pertinent to $X$. The pmf for $X$ is binomial with $7$ trials and success probability 0.78.